# Integrating next-intl to load data from strapi backend

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13, next-intl

I am trying to use Server Side Generation on my multilingual nextjs project. I have configured internationalization using `next-intl` library. I have a backend running on strapi headless CMS. I tried to load the data using `getServerSideProps, getStaticProps` but none of these functions are getting called. I can see that `getStaticPaths` is being called. I am new to next-js and could not find any resource related to loading data from a backend in the next-intl documentation. Please see the below for the code I tried. Any help is appreciated.

In my page.jsx

```
export async getServerSideProps({locale}) {
  const regulation = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/regulation');
  return {
    props: {
      regulation: regulation.json()
    }
  }
}
```

My directory structure is as follows

```
app
  [locale]
    about-us
      page.jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

In the app dir, there is no `getServerSideProps`.

The App directory utilises the React server component by default so you can directly fetch data in your server component.

Here are some resources:

- [Fetching data in Next.js 13](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching)
- [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components)